# Facebook Graph API search returns empty data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to get information about certain countries by calling the Facebook graph API. In the graph explorer i get a nice set of data returned to me, but when calling it in my fb app, it's empty. I have already checked all variables used in the php html request, and they are all fine. Any ideas?

[Link to explorer query](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1537331009838035/?method=GET&path=search%3Flocation_types%3D[%27country%27]%26type%3Dadgeolocation%26q%3DDenmark&version=v2.2&)

Explorer:

```
 https://graph.facebook/v2.2/search?location_types=['country']&type=adgeolocation&q=Denmark
```

PHP:

```
$get_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?location_types=['country']&type=adgeolocation&q=" . $country . "&access_token=" . $access_token;
```

print_r($get_url)

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?location_types=['country']&type=adgeolocation&q=Denmark&access_token=
```

Comment: What do you get as a result when you print_r() the variable $get_url? Is the url written there actually right?

Comment: @Jordy i have added the print to the original post :)

Comment: Without the access token of course

Comment: Have you gone through their Developers guide? It looks like they have set up their own classes that you can use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2

Comment: Im not really sure what you are referring to, tbh. Could you elaborate?

Comment: What kind of Access Token are you using in your app?

Comment: @Tobi You mean short or long-lived tokens ?

Comment: User, Page or App Access Token? The Graph Explorer uses User Access Tokens...

Comment: It's an user access token. I also tried pasting the token into the facebook graph explorer, and it returned a nice dataset

Answer (score 0):

Check if you use an User Access Token, which is required. You can check your Access Token type here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

for `/search` endpoint docs:

> All Graph API search queries require an access token included in the request. The type of access token you need depends on the type of search you're executing.
>
> - Searches across Page and Place objects requires an app access token.
> - All other endpoints require a user access token.

Comment: I have checked the access token used in the request, by pasting it into the facebook graph explorer, which worked fine.

Comment: I also just tried pasting the token into the site you linked to, which worked fine. It has all the right permissions too